# Angular / send another get request on every change on select

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two selects where with one select you choose cars and on another select you get specific models for that car with get request.

**component.html**

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Brand</mat-label>
    <mat-select multiple formControlName="Brand" (selectionChange)="getModels($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of vehicles" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>მოდელი</mat-label>
    <mat-select multiple formControlName="VehicleCategory">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of inputValue" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

so on every multiple choice it seperates request with commas like this:

```
http://localhost:5001/api/Vehicle/Brands/BENTLEY,DACIA,AUDI,HONDA/Models
```

here is the code i did for that:

**component.ts**

```
  getModels(form) {
        // get models
        this.inputValue = this.newCampaignForm.get("Brand").value;
        this.campaignService.getModels(this.inputValue).subscribe((data: any[])=>{
          this.inputValue = data;
        });
  }
```

**service.ts**

```
    public getModels(inputValue: string){
    return this.http.get(this.API_SERVER + '/Vehicle' + '/Brands' + '/' + inputValue + '/Models');
  }
```

What i want is for every time you select option new api call gets called, not with commas.

like this for example:

```
http://localhost:5001/api/Vehicle/Brands/OPEL/Models

http://localhost:5001/api/Vehicle/Brands/BMW/Models
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your selection

```
 getModels(event: any) {
    let value = event.value;
    value.forEach((item: any) => {
       console.log(item);
       this.campaignService.getModels(item).subscribe((data: any[]) => {
           this.inputValue = [...this.inputValue, ...data];
       });
    });
  }
```

and then you will able to pass the single brand to your service.

Here Stackblitz Example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqkbdp-fx49j4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts

Comment: Thanks it works, but the data on another input updates on every request, how can i do that it just adds data when many options are selected.

Comment: I have updated the answer.you need to push the data to the inputValue array. can you share your response for the service to have for more clarification

Comment: hey! thanks for answer. i have api on localhost so cant share it sry, it works! but it returns data in array as one option, i tried to split it but it doesnt work

Comment: can you share that array your return data then it will easy to assign

Comment: ["N4SG31-L", "ROC12-27N14", "ROC 12 27 CCE", "SKM 34-35A", "NH4G31-E", "ROC 12 27", "ROC 16.27 CC", "ROC 12.27CCE", "ROC 12.27CC30/40E", "ROC 12.27 NA", "ROC  12.27 CC", "SKM 34-33A", "NS4M31", "SKM 34-34 A", "89/3082", "SKM 34/3", "RP CC 12.27", "NS3G31-SP", "B 302", "RS CC  12.27", "NS4G31", "N4TS31", "SKM 34-32"]

Comment: hey, thanks for answer again, it does split on when i select on first time, but when i select more than two option it doesn't split and shows as one option,

Comment: when i select second option i get response like this:
[Array(2), "98C1350", "LVFS", "LVF S 3E 3", "EBS HALDEX", "LVFS3F1R", "S3E", "YS-2P5", "LVFS3E1R", "04C2567.004", "LVFS3F", "SR 2", "LVFS 3", "LVFS3E3R", "LVFS3E", "LVFS3F7R"]

Comment: put like following ...this.inputValue answer updated check that

Comment: thank u somuch it works! when more thing, selected options is also on other selects options, why is that?

Comment: don't use this.inputValue = event.value; I have updated earlier itself. see the answer again. i have changed it to local variable.

Comment: hi can i ask you another question? how can i remove data on second input if you uncheck it on first one?